# Replace URL String ${userid} with actual user id in the javascript object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string

I am getting the URL as below with `${USERID}` and I just want to replace with a.userId javascript object value.

```
angular.forEach(users.items, function(a))
{
    //navigationUrl="mysite.com/users/userId=${USERID}
    link = $scope.navigationUrl + a.userId
}
```

In the above code, I just need to replace the navigationUrl's ${USERID} with **a.userId**. 
How do I achieve this?

Comment: `'string'.replace` is what you are looking for.

Comment: yes. how do i acheive this on string.replace?

Comment: You read the documentation on `String.replace`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
angular.forEach(users.items, function(a))
{
    //navigationUrl="mysite.com/users/userId=${USERID}
    link = $scope.navigationUrl.replace("${USERID}", a.userId); 
}
```

assuming that your user id is `16` you will have `mysite.com/users/userId=16`

Comment: Thank you. if i want to replace two string then i need to do it in the next line? Example : i had to replace ${EMAIL} too

Comment: No, you can concat multiple ```replace```
```$scope.navigationUrl.replace("${USERID}", a.userId).replace("${EMAIL}", a.email);```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I have a hunch you're trying to use angular incorrectly. Forgive me if *my* hunch is incorrect.

Looks like you want to generate a list of links based on an array of users. Try this...

```
angular.module("demo", [])
  .controller("userController", function($scope) {
    $scope.users = [ 
      { name: "bob", userId: 1234 },
      { name: "jane", userId: 5678 }
    ];
  });

<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="userController">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="user in users">
      <a ng-href="mysite.com/users/userId={{user.userId}}">{{user.name}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

See a [working demo](http://codepen.io/jessegavin/pen/ONdLmJ?editors=1010)

Comment: Thank you.. i had to use string.replace() as below